# The person who is being rewarded is called what

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, grammar

How do you refer to a person who is being rewarded and the person who gives the reward?

For example, if you help me with something and I want to arrange a lunch to say thanks to you as a reward, what would someone call YOU and ME?

Comment: In some special cases, the recipient of an award has a special name: for example *laureate*.

Comment: In some contexts it'll be the *claimant*.

Comment: Depending on the type of reward, perhaps **honoree**.

Answer (score 3):

One who is receiving a reward, or anything for that matter, would be called the 'recipient', and the person presenting this award, or anything, would be the 'presenter' (which is commonly used to refer to an oral presentation, but can mean any sort of presentation as well).

Comment: Is there any specific terms for the `recipient` and `presenter` like recipient may be called `rewardee` and `presenter` `rewarderer`.?

Comment: Not any that I know of.  Certainly if the reward is for a contest, then the person getting the reward would be the "winner", but I don't think that's what you're looking for.

Comment: yes its not about contest

Comment: @Noor, a *rewarderer* would be a producer of rewarders, rather than a rewarder proper.

Comment: Of course you can invent words like *rewardee*, and most people will understand.  But (unless you are lucky) they won't catch on.

Comment: @GEdgar some may differ on just which outcome would be the luckier.

Answer (score 1):

Beneficiary sounds more suitable particularly in banking and financial scenario where reward is in form of points or money. Reward unlike Award need not to be an honor and could be a gift.